# How to use Newman to run only first X requests from the collection

Tags: command-line, postman, postman-collection-runner, newman, postman-newman

Is there a way to use Postman's Newman to send only the first X requests in the collection without editing the collection file?

Comment: No first x requests option in [here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/using-newman-cli/newman-options/)